# On an argument in the group $\text{PSL}(2,q)$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

I am looking for an explanation of the following paragraph.

"Let $G=\text{PSL}(2,q);\; q\equiv 3\;(\mod 4)$. Consider a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ which is elementary abelian of order $q$. If $B=N_{G}(P)$ be the Borel subgroup $G$, then $B$ is a Frobenius group with a cyclic complement of order $\frac{q-1}{2}$, which acts irreducibly on $P$. Hence, every element of $P$ is of the form $[g,a]$ for some $g\in P$ and an element $a$ in the complement."

My understanding so far: Take $Z=\{\pm I\}$. We can take
$$P=\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}Z \mid a\in \mathbb{F}_q\}; \;\; B=N_{G}(P)=\{\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & a \\ 0 & \lambda^{-1} \end{pmatrix}Z \mid a\in \mathbb{F}_q, \lambda \in \mathbb{F}_q^{*}\}.$$
Clear $|P|=q$ and $|B|=\frac{q(q-1)}{2}$. If $T\subset \text{PSL}(2,q)$ is taken to be the image of the diagonal torus in $\text{SL}(2,q)$ under the canonical homomorphism, then $T\subset B$ and $B=T\rtimes P$. We have that $T$ acts on $P$ via conjugation. But what does it exactly mean to say  that $T$ acts irreducibly on $P$ (and why?) and how does it imply that every element of $P$ is of the form $[g,a]$ where $g\in P$ and $a\in T$?

I greatly appreciate any kind of help in this direction.

Comment: For a fixed $1 \ne a$ in the complement $A$, the elements $[ g,a]$ with $g \in P$ form an $A$-invariant subgroup of $P$, so the result follows by the irreducibility of the action.

Comment: Thanks I understand that part. But why does $T$ acts irreducibly on $P$. I assume it means that under the conjugation action of $T$ on $P$, $P\setminus \{1\}$ is an orbit. But why so? My computations yield that: $$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0\\ 0 & \lambda ^{-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda^{-1} & 0\\ 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \lambda^2a\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: No it doesn't mean that $P \setminus \{1\}$ is an orbit, it means that if $1 \le Q \le P$ and $T \le N_G(Q)$, then $Q=1$ or $Q=P$. (In other words, the representation of $T$ over the field of order $p$ that si defined by this action is irreducible.) In fact there are two orbits of $T$ on $P \setminus \{1\}$,  both of length $(q-1)/2$.

Comment: Probably it seems that since $-1$ is not a square when $q\equiv 3(\mod 4)$ is playing a significant role here! And this argument will not work when $q\equiv 1 (\mod 4)$, but it is somehow not exactly clear to me. Further how the fact that $B$ is Frobenius is relevant here?

Comment: The fact that it is Frobenius tells you that there are two orbits both of length $|T| = (q-1)/2$, which implies that the action is irreducible. I think the same argument works when $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Okay now I understand the terminology. Is it obvious that $T$ acts on $P$ irreducibly? I mean does it require the fact that $q\equiv 3(\mod 4)$ or will it work for any $q$ odd.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! It is a little bit clear to me now.